# Django sort list

Tags: python, django

I have this queryset:

```
<QuerySet [<ProductAttributeValue: Utilizare: Lazurán 3 în 1 Lazur Protector se utilizează pentru lăcuirea decorativă.>, <ProductAttributeValue: Randament:  16 m2/lit., într-un strat>, <ProductAttributeValue: Straturi recomandate:  2>, <ProductAttributeValue: Timp de uscare la 23 °C:  2 ore>, <ProductAttributeValue: Timp de reaplicare la 23 °C:  2 ore>, <ProductAttributeValue: Mod de aplicare:  după o amestecare prealabilă se aplică cu pensula>, <ProductAttributeValue: Ambalare: 0.75L, 2.5L>]>
```

I would like to sort this queryset by fields name. For example when I display it I want that order:

> (Utilizare, Mod de aplicare, Randament, Ambalare, Straturi
> recomandate, Timp de uscare la 23 °C)

Actual code:

```
self.attribute_values.exclude(
            attribute__name__in=['Buttons', 'Ambalare']).exclude(
                attribute__type='file').order_by('pk')
```

There is any solution to sort this list in a given order?

Comment: could you please put the code where you actually make the call to the model to return this query set.

Comment: yes, I put the code where I make the call

Comment: Is question answered?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
querySet.objects.order_by('field_name')
```

From the django-documentation-site:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

Answer (score 0):

```
self.attribute_values.exclude(
            attribute__name__in=['Buttons', 'Ambalare']).exclude(
                attribute__type='file').order_by('pk').order_by('field_name')
```

That should work, and also take a quick read on the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by).

Comment: i get this error: Cannot resolve keyword 'Utilizare' into field. Choices are: attribute, attribute_id, entity_content_type, entity_content_type_id, entity_object_id, id, product, product_id, value_boolean, value_date, value_datetime, value_entity, value_file, value_float, value_image, value_integer, value_multi_option, value_option, value_option_id, value_richtext, value_text

Comment: That error happens when you are trying to reference a field that does not exist. is your field name on the model from where you got the query set called  ```'Utilizare'```?